# I want my sprite to touch the banana and collect it, but the code is not working

Tags: python, pygame

So I am making a game where you control a monkey with the arrow keys and you are supposed to touch the bananas in the map to collect them, I'm using the collide command so that if the monkey collides with the bananas, the bananas would dissapear and they would be added to a score counter, for some reason when I run my code, the whole thing suddenly stops and displays the number 1. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

screen_width = 864
screen_height = 936

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Flappy Bird')

bananacounter = 0


#define game variables
ground_scroll = 0
scroll_speed = 4
flying = False
game_over = False

#load images
bg = pygame.image.load('forest.png')
ground_img = pygame.image.load('ground.png')
Monkey = pygame.sprite.Sprite()

Monkey.image = pygame.image.load("monkey.png")
#boundaries
Monkey.rect = Monkey.image.get_rect()       
x=400
y=200
movex=0
movey=0

banana = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
banana.image = pygame.image.load("smallest banana.png")
#boundaries 
banana.rect = banana.image.get_rect()       
x2 = 0
y2 = 0 
movex=0
movey=0

banana2= pygame. sprite.Sprite()
banana2.image= pygame.image.load('small banana 2.png')
banana2.rect=banana2.image.get_rect()
x3= 100
y3 = 500
movex=0
movey=0

banana3= pygame. sprite.Sprite()
banana3.image= pygame.image.load('small banana 3.png')
banana3.rect=banana3.image.get_rect()
x4= 500
y4 = 500
movex=0
movey=0

banana4= pygame. sprite.Sprite()
banana4.image= pygame.image.load('green banana.png')
banana4.rect=banana3.image.get_rect()
x5= 500
y5 = 500
movex=0
movey=0




banana.rect.topleft=(x2,y2)
screen.blit(Monkey.image, banana.rect)
x=x+movex
y=y+movey
pygame.display.update()
event=pygame.event.poll()

banana2.rect.topleft=(x3,y3)
screen.blit(Monkey.image, banana2.rect)
x=x+movex
y=y+movey
pygame.display.update()
event=pygame.event.poll()

banana3.rect.topleft=(x4,4)
screen.blit(Monkey.image, banana3.rect)
x=x+movex
y=y+movey
pygame.display.update()
event=pygame.event.poll()

banana4.rect.topleft=(x5,y5)
screen.blit(Monkey.image, banana3.rect)
x=x+movex
y=y+movey
pygame.display.update()
event=pygame.event.poll()




while(True):
  
    #draw background
    screen.blit(bg, (0,0))
        
    screen.blit(banana.image,banana.rect)

    screen.blit(banana2.image,banana2.rect)

    screen.blit(banana3.image,banana3.rect)

    screen.blit(banana4.image,banana4.rect)

    #draw the ground
    screen.blit(ground_img, (ground_scroll, 768)) 

    
    Monkey.rect.topleft=(x,y)
    screen.blit(Monkey.image, Monkey.rect)
    x=x+movex
    y=y+movey
    pygame.display.update()
    event=pygame.event.poll()
  
    if(event.type==pygame.QUIT):
     break
    elif(event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
    #KEYDOWN means a key is pressed
     if(event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):
      movex=10
     elif(event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):
      movex=-10
     elif(event.key==pygame.K_UP):
        movey=-10
     elif(event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):
      movey=10
     elif(event.type==pygame.KEYUP):
      movex=10
     elif (event.type==pygame.KEYUP): 
      movey = 0
      movex = 0
      pygame.display.update()
    
    while (pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Monkey,banana)):
    #banana disappears by moving off screen
     x2=800
    y2=600
    #add to banana counter
    bananacounter +=1
    #check that counter's working
    print(bananacounter)
    break
    #update screen
    pygame.display.update()

    



pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This question is a bit outside the scope of stack overflow. Generally, questions that are more focused/specific do better. I recommend looking at your code and stripping away components; simplifying your project until the issue is obvious, then build it back up. Debugging is 70% of the coding process. (planning is 29%, actually coding is 1%)

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is that you're not indenting the rest of the collision code after x2=800.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).